# PDO query duplicate one bind Instead of their own

Tags: php, pdo

I've an question about my CRUD plugin. I'm working on the update section and when i update the query, all columns al get the ':id' as value and not their own ones.

Below my debugDumpParams();

```
string(7) "column1"
string(4) "help"
string(7) "column2"
string(4) "help"
string(2) "id"
string(1) "4"

SQL: [69] UPDATE test SET column1 = :column1, column2 = :column2 WHERE id = :id

Params:  3
Key: Name: [8] :column1
paramno=-1
name=[8] ":column1"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [8] :column2
paramno=-1
name=[8] ":column2"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [3] :id
paramno=-1
```

Al other sections of my CRUD are working and the insert works almost on the same way, so i don't no what i do worng, maybe someone from outside can see the eror that i can't see.

Below my code:

```
}elseif($type == 'update') {

    $columns = array_keys($column);
    $col_set = implode(",",$columns);

    $query_array = array();

    foreach ($column as $key => $value) {

        if($key == 'id'){
            $query_array_id = $key.' = :'.$key;
        }else{
            $query_array[] = $key.' = :'.$key;
        }

    }
    $query = ''.$query.' '.$table.' SET '.implode(", ",$query_array).' WHERE '.$query_array_id.'';

    $dbh_query = $dbh->prepare($query);

    foreach ($column as $key => $value) {

        $dbh_query->bindParam(':'.$key, $key);
        var_dump($key);
        $key = trim($value);
        var_dump($key);

    }

    $dbh_query->execute();  
    $dbh_query->debugDumpParams();

    echo '<br/>';

    return $dbh_query;
}
```

Below what i get in the database:

```
'column1' => '4',   
'column2' => '4', 
'id' => '4'
```

Thats wrong because my function call is:

```
$postFile->processing('update', 'test', array(
                                              'column1' => 'help',  
                                              'column2' => 'help', 
                                              'id' => '4'
                                             ));
```

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE!**

Change a little bit of my code and it works, thanks a lot!

```
}elseif($type == 'update') {

    $columns = array_keys($column);
    $col_set = implode(",",$columns);

    $query_array = array();

    foreach ($column as $key => $value) {

        if($key == 'id'){
            $query_array_id = $key.' = :'.$key;
        }else{
            $query_array[] = $key.' = :'.$key;
        }

    }

    $query = ''.$query.' '.$table.' SET '.implode(", ",$query_array).' WHERE '.$query_array_id.'';

    $dbh_query = $dbh->prepare($query);

    $dbh_query->execute($column);


    return $dbh_query;
```

Comment: $dbh_query->bindParam(':'.$key, $key); -> $dbh_query->bindParam(':'.$key, $value);

Comment: Pieter, dank voor je reactie, alleen de $key moet het zelfde zijn omdat in de trim de value wordt gedefiniëerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send your data right into execute. without using bindParam

```
$dbh_query = $dbh->prepare($query);
$dbh_query->execute($column);
```

but you have to understand that all this spaghetti

```
''.$query.' '.$table.' SET '.implode(", ",$query_array).' WHERE '.$query_array_id.''
```

is severely vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: I have change it, and check it on sql injection.